# Unit testing with and without requiring ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I've extracted a single class from a Rails app into [a gem](https://github.com/Flambino/week_sauce). It's very, very simple, but of course I'd like to fully test it (I'm using rspec).

The class does some simple date-calculation. It's not dependent on Rails, but since it started out in a Rails app, and is still used there, it uses ActiveSupport's time zone-aware methods when it can. But, if ActiveSupport isn't available, it should use the std-lib `Date` methods.

Specifically, it only does this in one single place: Defaulting an optional argument to "today's date":

```
arg ||= if Date.respond_to?(:current)
  Date.current # use ActiveSupport's time zone-aware mixin if possible
else
  Date.today   # stdlib fallback
end
```

Question is: How do I properly test this? If I require ActiveSupport in my `spec_helper.rb`, it'll obviously *always* use that. If I don't require it anywhere, it'll never use it. And if I require it for a single example group, rspec's random execution order makes the testing unpredictable, as I don't know when AS will be required.

I can require maybe it in a `before(:all)` in a nested group, as nested groups are (I believe) processed highest to deepest. But that seems terribly inelegant.

I could also split the specs into two files, and run them separately, but again, that seems unnecessary.

I could also disable rspec's random ordering, but that's sort of going against the grain. I'd rather have it as randomized as possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to mock the `current` and `today` methods, and use those for testing. Eg:

```
# you won't need these two lines, just there to make script work standalone
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'

def test_method(arg = nil)
    arg ||= if Date.respond_to?(:current)
      Date.current # use ActiveSupport's time zone-aware mixin if possible
    else
      Date.today   # stdlib fallback
    end
    arg
end

describe "test_method" do
    let(:test_date) { Date.new(2001, 2, 3) }
    it "returns arg unchanged if not nil" do
        test_method(34).should == 34
    end

    context "without Date.current available" do
        before(:all) do
            Date.stub(:today) { test_date }
        end
        it "returns Date.today when arg isn't present" do
            test_method.should == test_date
        end
    end

    context "with Date.current available" do
        before(:all) do
            Date.stub(:current) { test_date }
        end
        it "returns Date.current when arg isn't present" do
            test_method.should == test_date
        end
    end
end
```

Running with `rspec test.rb` results in the tests passing.

Also, the stubs are present only in each context, so it doesn't matter what order the specs are run in.

Comment: Of course! I didn't even consider stubs since everything else in the spec was so straight-forward. Why is it whenever I ask a question on SO, I feel like a complete dunce when I get an answer? :) But thanks regardless! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more than a little perverse, but it *should* work.  Include ActiveSupport, and then:

```
context "without ActiveSupport's Date.current" do
  before(:each) do
    class Date
      class << self
        alias_method :current_backup, :current
        undef_method :current
      end
    end
  end

  # your test

  after(:each) do
    class Date
      class << self
        alias_method :current, :current_backup
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I can't really recommend this; I would prefer to split out this one spec and run it separately as you suggested.

Comment: Heh, I considered that myself, but as you say: It's kinda perverse :) That said, it'd probably work just fine... but still: gross :)